# Twitter user_timeline API not showing retweets

Tags: json, api, twitter, tweets

I'm having a problem with integrating the Twitter API into my website to make a small feed of my latest tweets.
I call the JSON API using this URL:

> `http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=<my username>&count=2`

I get a proper feed, and when I parse it it's completely fine. Though I noticed that after I retweeted a tweet from my account, the JSON feed started showing one less entry at the bottom (I had 2 tweets, now it's showing 1).

I thought that it was because the API was now returning two tweets one of which was my retweet, and had popped out the oldest tweet, though the retweet was not showing up.

After inspecting the actual JSON code returned by the API, I discovered that there's no trace of my oldest tweet (the one that popped away) nor of the new retweet. The only shown tweet is my second one, the one before I retweeted.

Does anyone know how to solve that? I don't want the stream on my website to show retweets, so this is okay, but I also don't want my retweets to make the real tweets disappear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` is not a promise of how many tweets will be returned. It is more a max count. If you want to increase your chances of receiving two normal tweets set `count` to 10 or 20 and only display the latest two.

Comment: @danrhul it wasn't a work around at the time I posted it. It was how the API had to be used.

Comment: @abraham Then this answer is outdated and is now a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Twitter has provided the `include_rts` parameter. The `count` seems to be the count *including* retweets, even if you don't have `include_rts` enabled (which in my opinion is quite lame/annoying).

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=<my username>&count=2&include_rts=true
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on the api for the user_timeline [here](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) I would suggest making some more tweets to see if the problem continues, it may have just been a fluke.